# Replace Pending with NA

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query which returns the result like below,

```
ID  Status
1   Approved
2   Rejected
3   Pending
4   Pending
```

The goal is to replace the entries after rejected with 'NA'.I tried using Case Statement but Only the third row gets changed as NA.Can anyone help me out?

The query i used is ,

```
   case when Lag(a.Status,1) over (order by a.ID)='Rejected'
   then 'NA'
   else a.Status 
   end  as Status`
```

the expected output is ,

```
Approved
Rejected
NA
NA
```

The goal is to Replace all pending after a rejected status with NA.

Comment: Show us your SQL query, there's not enough information here.

Comment: case when Lag(a.Status,1) over (order by a.ID)='Rejected' then 'NA'  else a.Status end  as Status

Comment: Show us your `case` _expression_ query attempt!

Comment: [edit] your question with the full SQL please.

Comment: i modified the question guys

Comment: Add some more sample data, having several Rejected rows, and also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a windowed `MAX()` or `SUM()` while checking the `rejected` condition.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Status') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Status

CREATE TABLE #Status (
    ID INT IDENTITY,
    GroupID INT,
    Status VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #Status (
    GroupID,
    Status)
VALUES
    (1, 'Approved'),
    (1, 'Rejected'),
    (1, 'Pending'),
    (1, 'Pending'),
    (1, 'Pending'),

    (2, 'Pending'),
    (2, 'Approved'),
    (2, 'Pending'),
    (2, 'Rejected'),
    (2, 'Pending'),
    (2, 'Pending')

;WITH WindowedMax AS
(
    SELECT
        S.ID,
        S.GroupID,
        S.Status,
        RejectedCue = MAX(CASE WHEN S.Status = 'Rejected' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY S.GroupID ORDER BY S.ID ASC)
    FROM
        #Status AS S
)
UPDATE S SET
    Status = 'NA'
FROM
    WindowedMax AS W
    INNER JOIN #Status AS S ON W.ID = S.ID
WHERE
    W.RejectedCue = 1 AND W.Status <> 'Rejected'

SELECT * FROM #Status AS S ORDER BY S.ID

/* Results:

    ID  GroupID Status
    1   1   Approved
    2   1   Rejected
    3   1   NA
    4   1   NA
    5   1   NA

    6   2   Pending
    7   2   Approved
    8   2   Pending
    9   2   Rejected
    10  2   NA
    11  2   NA

*/
```

The `PARTITION BY` will determine how to differentiate groups within your data and the `ORDER BY` will determine the order of each status within each partition.

---

**EDIT**: To be used as a view.

```
;WITH WindowedMax AS
(
    SELECT
        S.ID,
        S.GroupID,
        S.Status,
        RejectedCue = MAX(CASE WHEN S.Status = 'Rejected' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY S.GroupID ORDER BY S.ID ASC)
    FROM
        #Status AS S
)
SELECT
    S.ID,
    S.GroupID,
    Status = CASE WHEN W.RejectedCue = 1 AND W.Status <> 'Rejected' THEN 'NA' ELSE S.Status END
FROM
    WindowedMax AS W
    INNER JOIN #Status AS S ON W.ID = S.ID
```

Comment: Can this me used in a view?

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to this question is:

```
select (case when id > max(case when status = 'Rejected' then id end) over (order by id) and
                  status = 'Pending'
             then 'NA' else status
        end) as new_status
from t;
```

This converts *all* "Pending" values after the last "Rejected" to "NA".  I'm not sure that is sensible when there might be more rows in the table, but it answers this specific question with the sample data you have provided.

Answer (score -1):

*Replace all records after Rejected* isnt the same as *replace Pending"*

Anyway this would work for 2nd case

```
SELECT REPLACE(MYCOLUMN, 'Pending', 'NA')
```

check this approach too:

```
declare @test table (ID int, Status nvarchar(50))
INSERT INTO @test VALUES
(1,   'Approved'),
(2,   'Pending'),
(3,   'Rejected'),
(4,   'Pending'),
(5,   'Pending'),
(6,   'Approved'),
(7,   'Pending'),
(8,   'Maybe Pending'),
(9,   'Pending'),
(10,  'Rejected'),
(11,  'Pending'),
(12,  'Pending')


SELECT  id, case
        when Lag(a.Status,1) over (order by a.ID) in ('Rejected', 'Pending')
        and A.STATUS = 'Pending'
        then 'NA'
        else a.Status
        end  as Status FROM @test a
```

Output:

```
id  Status
1   Approved
2   Pending
3   Rejected
4   NA
5   NA
6   Approved
7   Pending
8   Maybe Pending
9   Pending
10  Rejected
11  NA
12  NA
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you comment your downvotes :) This actually answers the OP question

Comment: i should check the Rejected and replace the pending with NA.

Comment: This would be a terrible way to do it. Imagine a future status called `Billing Pending`, your query would turn that into `Billing NA`. It also doesn't answer the question at all. OP wants all statuses **after** rejected to be changed.

Comment: nothing in the OP post makes us think there will be different future values. It's obviously designed for static purposes.

Comment: Yes there is, they said *Only the third row gets changed* so they clearly want all of them changed.

Comment: not really: `Approved`, `Rejected`, `Pending`, `Pending`, `NewValue` in this dataset if _All records after Rejected are replaced_ it would be `Approved`, `Rejected`, `NA`, `NA`, `NA`: so it makes difference as u can notice.

Comment: But what if the data was `Approved`, `Pending`, `Approved`, `Rejected`, `Pending`, `Pending`?

Comment: My 1st notice was about the question being not clear and your case explains the same thing. This answer covers the 2nd case (all `pendings` are replaced with `NA`)

Comment: If the question isn't clear, then don't answer it. Encourage the OP to make it better first. And there is no "2nd case", there is only 1 requirement here and your answer doesn't fit it.

Comment: it actually does :) But anyway let the OP check it

Comment: How does it satisfy the requirement *to replace the entries after rejected with 'NA*? Your code replaces *all* of them.

Comment: op edited question title, it litterally says "Replace Pending with NA". So please stop spam and let him check it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172881/discussion-between-b3s-and-davidg).